# Problem with open new browser using router in Vue/Electron. Redirecting to default route

Tags: node.js, vue.js, electron, vuetify.js

I'm trying to open a new window using Vue/Electron but the new windows is opening on default rounte instead the needed route.

*The route on navigation-drawer is working well.

file: router/index.js

```
import Process from '@/components/ProcessManager/Process.vue'
export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      component: require('@/components/LandingPage').default
    },
    {
      path: 'process',
      name: 'process',
      component: Process,
    },
    {
      path: '*',
      redirect: '/'
    }
  ]
```

file:main/index.js

```
const processURL = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'
  ? `http://localhost:9080/#/process`
  : `file://${__dirname}/index.html#process`

function createWindow2 () {
  let win = new BrowserWindow({ width: 400, height: 320, webPreferences: {webSecurity: false} })
  win.loadURL(processURL)
  win.on('closed', () => {
    win = null
  })
}
```

[image: Windows opening on same route]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it loads the index.html but does not start the app, and the reason is shown in the error message in the screenshot you supplied.

Looking at the error message, you can read [here](http://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/security#2-do-not-enable-nodejs-integration-for-remote-content) what's going on.